# counting characters in the input with while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, eof

I wrote a simple c program to count number of characters

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    long nc;
    nc = 0;

    while (getchar() != EOF)
      ++nc;

    printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

This program is not printing me the characters. On testing different cases, I found that I am stuck in an infinite `while()` loop.

Comment: Try to use: `while (getchar() != '\n')`. Remember that `getchar()` doesn't terminate until you send an enter (`\n`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (getchar() != '\n')
   ++nc;
printf("%ld \n",nc);
```

Worked!

Answer (score 7):

> ***This program isn't printing me the characters***

It won't. You did not add any statement to *print* them.

> ***I found that i'm stuck in an infinite while loop***

If you don't *hit* the *breaking* condition, you'll be in the loop. You need to get `EOF` to exit the loop. use

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (on windows)
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (on linux)

Now, the solutions:

1. `getchar()` won't print the values. You have to store the values and print explicitly (if you want to) using , maybe `putchar()`.
2. You either supply `EOF` or change the breaking condition of `while()` to come out of the *essential* infinite loop otherwise.

---

Apart from the coding issues, you need to think about the logic, too. In the present form of the code, `getchar()` counts the *newline* (`\n`) as a *valid* character, too. To explain, an input in the form of

> $ ./a.out  <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
>   a      <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
>   s      <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
>   d      <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
>   f       <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
>   g      <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
>   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Will produce a result

> 10

but that is **not** what we generally call *counting the character*. You may want to review this part of the logic, too.

That said, the recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int c;
    long nc = 0;

    while ( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n' ) ++nc;

    printf( "%ld\n", nc );
}
```

You have to generate the EOF state ( Ctrl+d in UNIX-systems or CTRL+z in Windows) or simply press Enter.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh Thanks. I have made this mistake as result of copy and paste.:)

Comment: No issues sir, happens with all of us. Just noted the thing, so thought of putting a note. Cheers :-)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It still didn't print out the number of characters.

Comment: @katyal93  I run the program and it output a correct result. Maybe your console window is closed very quickly. In this case after  the printf statement you can place two getchar one after another that there would be a delay.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    long nc = 0;

    while ( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n' ) 
    ++nc;

    printf( "%ld\n", nc );
}
```

Comment: this line: 'while ( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF || c != '\n' ) ' is staying in the loop, forever, as 'c' cannot be both EOF and '\n'   Suggest: 'while ( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n' ) '